# Gradle incremental build on bitbucket multi step pipeline

Tags: gradle, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I cannot make the gradle incremental feature work on a bitbucket pipeline with multiple steps.
What I like to have is:

1. A step that compile the code
2. A step that test the code being compiled (without a need to recompile)

Reading the doc I added the build folder and even the .gradle folder as artifacts of the compile step:

```
default:
    - step:
        name: Compile the application
        caches:
          - gradlew
        script:
          - ./gradlew core:compileJava
        artifacts:
          - .gradle/**
          - build/**
    - step:
        name: Run the unit tests
        caches:
          - gradlew
        script:
          - ./gradlew core:test
```

Using the `find` command I can see the compiled classes and the .gradle files
into the `unit test` step.

However the `unit test` step always rerun the compilation process and using the `-i` option it outputs:

```
Task ':core:compileJava' is not up-to-date because:
  Output property 'options.generatedSourceOutputDirectory' file /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/core/build/generated/sources/annotationProcessor/java/main has been removed.
  Output property 'options.headerOutputDirectory' file /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/core/build/generated/sources/headers/java/main has been removed.
```

This seems like a trivial setup am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Why not combine the two steps?

Comment: Because I'd like to see which exact step failed instead of having to look at the pipeline log to figure out whether the test or the compilation failed.

Comment: is gradlew the correct name for the cache? The bitbucket docs use gradle : https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/cache-dependencies/#Set-up-caching

Comment: I tried both. Finally I forced the test task to skip the compilation task. It works fine since the compiled files are on the disk but still I cannot understand why it doesn't detect it out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem.
The problem seems to be caused by the exclusion of empty directories when uploading files to artifacts.

Try running `mkdir -p build/generated/sources/{annotationProcessor,headers}/java/main` before executing `./gradlew core:test`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I finally used another workaround, I run the tests with a `-x compileJava` flag and it works.